# How and what calls the ConfigureServices and Configure methods of startup.cs in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

The Main method of Program.cs is the entry point of application. As you can see in the .NET Core default code created when we create any project.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And in startup class we have two In-build method i.e `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` as shown below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
}
```

I just want to know that how these methods is invoked. As we know that to invoked any method we have to create a object of the class and using that object we can execute the method, then how these(`ConfigureServices` and `Configure`) methods execute without creating any object.

Comment: The code is open source and on github. Sure you can check the repository and see how it uses conventions to find and invoke those methods. The docs also explain the fundamentals about the startup class.

Comment: Can you please share me the link of startup page logic of github. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f3f9a1cdbcd06b298035b523732b9f45b1408461/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/StartupLoader.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an overly simplified explanation,

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
```

method call returns an object for default webhost builder which implements `IWebHostBuilder`. Then `UseStartup()` extension method configures created webhost builder using the Startup class you provide. `UseStartup()` method can identify your startup class since you specify as the generic argument. UseStartup() cantains the implementation to invoke `ConfigureServices` and  `Configure` methods which you provide by using the reflection. Note that to invoke a method one can use reflection also other than creating an instance of a class.

Comment: As you said "UseStartup() cantains the implementation to invoke ConfigureServices and  Configure methods which you provide by using the reflection."

Can we see the code how reflection calling these method?

Comment: Here you provide the startup class. But if you dont provide ConfigureServices and  Configure methods, then nothing will happen. Framework uses .net reflection to get the type information for your class and using the reflection to invoke your methods. But framework will only search for the above methods. Therefore you need to provide them.

Comment: To learn how reflection works, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are called by the ASP.NET Core framework. Note that in your `Main` method you have this call:

```
.UseStartup<Startup>()
```

Where you specify the class to use for the startup, in this case `Startup`. The `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods are called by convention. If those methods are found in the class specified in the `UseStartup` extension, they will be called.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know about convention. Can you please short brief me. As I new in .net core

Comment: 'Convention' just means an agreed structure. The framework looks for the methods and calls them if they are found.

Comment: It means that these method is already defined in the back side of framework.?

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a step back and try to understand what are we trying to do here -
We are setting Up the Host and Host originates the request pipeline. Now both Configure and Configure services are like the rooms where the requests are configured through middleware or services.

Now as you built the Host and Ran it from Program.cs and injected StartUp as already said, using reflection, stitches up the Request Pipleline origin and configured with these two methods so that it can handle all the requests

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out both of these methods and you'll get exceptions as a result:

1. "System.InvalidOperationException: A public method named 'ConfigureDevelopment' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Your_WebApplication.Startup' type".
2. System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'

**Configure** -  This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
**ConfigureServices** - This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.